# next item of list inside dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe that has a column where each row has a list.
I want to get the next element after the value I am looking for (in another column).

For example:
Let's say I am looking for 'b':

```
|lists    |next_element|
|---------|------------|
|[a,b,c,d]| c          | #(c is the next value after b)
|[c,b,a,e]| a          | #(a is the next value after b)
|[a,e,f,b]| []         | #(empty, because there is no next value after b)
```

*All lists have the element. There are no lists without the value I am looking for

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please share your code and explain what you expected from it and what you got instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a function and use `apply`.

```
value = 'b'

def get_next(x):
    get_len = len(x)-1
    for i in x:
        if value.lower() == i.lower():
            curr_idx = x.index(i)
            if curr_idx == get_len:
                return []
            else:
                return x[curr_idx+1]

df["next_element"] = df["lists"].apply(get_next)
df
Out[649]: 
          lists next_element
0  [a, b, c, d]            c
1  [c, b, a, e]            a
2  [a, e, f, b]           []
```

Answer (score 0):

First observation, since you want the next element of a list of string elements, the expected data type should be a string for that column, and not a list.

So, instead of the `next_element` columns as `[c, a, []]` its better to use `[c, a, None]`

Secondly, you should try avoiding `apply` methods directly over series and instead utilize the `str` methods that pandas provides for series which is a vectorized way of solving such problems super fast.

---

With the above in mind, let's try this completely vectorized one-liner -

```
element = 'b'

df['next_element'] = df.lists.str.join('').str.split(element).str[-1].str[0]
```

```
          lists next_element
0  [a, b, c, d]            c
1  [c, b, a, e]            a
2  [a, e, f, b]          NaN
```

1. First I combine each row as a single string [a,b,c,d]->'abcd`
2. Next I split this by 'b' to get substrings
3. I pick the last element from this list and finally the first element from that, for each row, using `str` functions which are vectorized over each row.

Read more about `pandas.Series.str` methods on official documentation/tutorial [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/user_guide/text.html#string-methods)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = df.assign(next_element = "")
print(df)
for ind in df.index:
    c= df["Lists"][ind]
    for i,v in enumerate(c):
        if v == "b":
            df["next_element"][ind] = c[i+1]
            
print(df)
```

Try with this one you will get the exact output what you expected.